# Golang code that gets data from Kubernetes API and Writes to Spanner

Tags: go

Code for writing a Writer that is used to dump data in a Spanner table.

Specifically concerned about the function: `func (s *SpannerClient) Write(resp Response) (n int, err error)` given it has too many `if`s.

```
package spanner

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"

    "cloud.google.com/go/spanner"
)

// Writer is an interface for anything that can write data.
type Writer interface {
    Write(p Response) (n int, err error)
}

type SpannerWriterAdapter struct {
    Client Writer
}

// SpannerClient is a type that implements the Writer interface and writes to Spanner.
type SpannerClient struct {
    Client *spanner.Client
    Ctx    context.Context
}

type Metadata struct {
    Labels            map[string]string `json:"labels"`
    CreationTimestamp string            `json:"creationTimestamp"`
}

type Data struct {
    ApiKey string `json:"api-key"`
}

type Response struct {
    Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
}

type Payload struct {
    Metadata Metadata               `json:"metadata"`
    Data     map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}

// Declare Error constants
var (
    ErrApiKeyNotFound    = errors.New("api-key not found")
    ErrProjectIdNotFound = errors.New("project id not found")
    ErrUserLabelNotFound = errors.New("user label not found")
    ErrEnvNotFound       = errors.New("env not found")
)

// Declare key constants
var (
    APIKEY_KEY      = "api-key"
    PROJECT_KEY     = "project"
    USER_KEY        = "user"
    USER_LABEL_KEY  = "user_label"
    ENVIRONMENT_KEY = "env"
)

// Declare Spanner table and related constants
var (
    SPANNER_TABLE_NAME = "dump_table" // this name can't be changed
)

// New creates a new Spanner client and returns it as a Writer.
func New(ctx context.Context, db string) (Writer, error) {
    client, err := spanner.NewClient(ctx, db)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &SpannerClient{
        Client: client,
        Ctx:    ctx,
    }, nil
}

// Write writes a Payload to Spanner.
func (s *SpannerClient) Write(resp Response) (n int, err error) {
    apiKey, ok := resp.Payload.Data[APIKEY_KEY].(string)
    if !ok {
        return 0, ErrApiKeyNotFound
    }
    projectID, ok := resp.Payload.Metadata.Labels[PROJECT_KEY]
    if !ok {
        return 0, ErrProjectIdNotFound
    }
    userID, ok := resp.Payload.Metadata.Labels[USER_KEY]
    if !ok {
        return 0, ErrUserLabelNotFound
    }
    userLabel, ok := resp.Payload.Metadata.Labels[USER_LABEL_KEY]
    if !ok {
        return 0, ErrEnvNotFound
    }
    environment, ok := resp.Payload.Metadata.Labels[ENVIRONMENT_KEY]
    if !ok {
        return 0, ErrEnvNotFound
    }
    creationTimestamp := resp.Payload.Metadata.CreationTimestamp
    mutation := spanner.InsertOrUpdate(
        SPANNER_TABLE_NAME,
        []string{"id", "project_id", "user_id", "label", "value", "environment", "created_on", "updated_on", "deleted_on"},
        []interface{}{apiKey, projectID, userID, userLabel, apiKey, environment, creationTimestamp, spanner.CommitTimestamp, nil},
    )
    _, err = s.Client.Apply(s.Ctx, []*spanner.Mutation{mutation})
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return 1, nil
}

// This function is critical so that we can decouple tackling raw bytes and json response
func (s *SpannerWriterAdapter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // Convert byte slice to Payload. This assumes a simple JSON representation.
    // Adjust the conversion as per your actual data structure.
    var response Response
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &response); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    data := response.Payload.Data
    // labels := response.Payload.Metadata.Labels
    apiKey, ok := data[APIKEY_KEY].(string)
    if !ok || apiKey == "" {
        return 0, nil // ignore this data as there is no api-key
    }
    _, ok = response.Payload.Metadata.Labels[PROJECT_KEY]
    if !ok {
        return 0, nil // ignore this data as there is no project key
    }
    // Write the data that is in the vault namespace and has both the keys: 'api-key' and 'project'
    return s.Client.Write(response)
}
```